# How to pass parameter to graphql query?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, graphql, apollo

I am trying to use Apollo graphql in a Meteor blaze project.

I am using the package from `swydo:blaze-apollo`.
It is fine to get the data from mongoDB by using graphql query.

```
// Using this one can get data
const LOCATION_COUNTRY_QUERY = gql`
{
    locations(location_type: "Country"){
        location_id
        name
        iso_code
    }
}
`;

Template.home.onCreated(function(){
    const country = this.gqlQuery({query: LOCATION_COUNTRY_QUERY}).get();
    console.log(country.locations); // Which will show an array list of country.
});
```

However, I don't want to hard code "Country" in the query. I want to pass the String into the query then get the data with other location_type. But I cannot find any article about it and the gql syntax just blocking any parameter.

Anyone has similar experience and can give any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use GraphQL Variables to accomplish the job.
First, declare the variable to your `LOCATION_COUNTRY_QUERY`:

```
const LOCATION_COUNTRY_QUERY = gql`
query locationCountryQuery($locationType: String!){
    locations(location_type: $locationType){
        location_id
        name
        iso_code
    }
}
`;
```

Now you can provide a new `variables` option to the query:

```
Template.home.onCreated(function(){
    const country = this.gqlQuery({query: LOCATION_COUNTRY_QUERY, variables: {locationType: "Country"}).get();
    console.log(country.locations); // Which will show an array list of country.
});
```