# using variables in gql apollo query

Tags: reactjs, apollo, gql

I have this gql query that searches for a certain product, but this ID is hardcoded
how can I replace this ID **(product(id: "apple-imac-2021"))** with a variable ?

```
const CURRENT_PRODUCT = gql`
    query {
        product(id: "apple-imac-2021") {
            name
            inStock
            gallery
            description
            brand
            attributes {
                name
                type
                items {
                    value
                }
            }
            prices {
                currency {
                    label
                    symbol
                }
                amount
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632152/how-to-pass-parameter-to-graphql-query

Comment: i am using useQuery() hook to execute this query , can't I mention the variable inside CURRENT_PRODUCT gql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on this example :

that is the solution, you should do the following in query :

```
query product($id : String!) {
        product(id: $id) {
            name
            inStock
            gallery
            description
            brand
            attributes {
                name
                type
                items {
                    value
                }
            }
            prices {
                currency {
                    label
                    symbol
                }
                amount
            }
        }
    }
    `;
```

and then assign the $id variable when using useQuery() like that :

```
    const { loading, data } = useQuery(CURRENT_PRODUCT, {
        variables: {
            id: id,
        },
    });
```